# Error - The service is invalid. Please check your setup and try again. (0xE8000022)

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, installation

I keep on getting this error when I try to run the app on my iPhone. I'm running Xcode 7.3 and had started to get this error on Xcode 7.2. I have tried pretty much every solution I could find, but none seem to work. I also tried using the previous versions of Xcode, and didn't seem to resolve the problem either. My iPhone is running iOS 9.1. Is there any work around this?

These are some of the solutions I followed but didn't work:

[Error : The service is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160299/error-the-service-is-invalid)

[how to remove error the service is invalid please check your setup and try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160208/howto-remove-error-the-service-is-invalide-please-check-your-setup-and-try)

[Warning dialog "The Service is Invalid" when building and running App in XCode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538360/warning-dialog-the-service-is-invalid-when-building-and-running-app-in-xcode-4)

Comment: If you're jailbroken you can try the answer I posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36267670/xcode-7-3-ios-9-1-jailbroken-please-check-your-setup-and-try-again-0xe80?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when attempting to register for remote push notifications in my app, in the end it was because I had assigned the iOS Team provisioning profile to the app as opposed to the one I generated in the developer portal. The error occurs because the one that xcode generates doesn't include include permissions for remote notifications.