# Xcode 7.3 - iOS 9.1 - Jailbroken - Please check your setup and try again. (0xE8000022)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, jailbreak

I'm trying to load my application on my ***Jailbroken*** iPhone 6S running iOS 9.1. I previously had an iPhone 5s running some type of iOS 8 and it was ***also jailbroken***, but I did not have any problems running my apps on that. I have tried all solutions for the specific error I'm getting, but it has not helped at all. Also, I did run my application successfully on an iPad for whatever that means.

***I have tried every solution on this page:
[Error : The service is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160299/error-the-service-is-invalid)***

**iPhone Specs & Related Stuff:**

iPhone 6s - iOS 9.1 - 13B143

AppSync Unified v5.8 - AppCake

Jailbroken w/ Pangu 9

**Xcode Build Settings - Code Signing: (If it helps)** [Build Settings - Code Signing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tEUe.png)

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**: **Forcing iOS to mount the DeveloperDiskImage does the trick.**

1. SSH into your iDevice and duplicate the /Developer folder to /DeveloperPangu, just to be safe.
2. Exit your ssh session, or open a new tab
3. Download the binary folder from: https://github.com/kpwn/yalu/blob/master/bin/,
4. `cd` to the downloaded folder
5. Execute this command:`./ideviceimagemounter /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/9.1/DeveloperDiskImage.dmg`
6. Unplug your device
7. Open Xcode and and plug your device back in
8. Happy debugging! (Just make sure you don't reboot)

And when your done developing:

1. SSH into your iDevice
2. Do `ps aux | grep Developer`
3. kill all the processes that are listed
4. Do `umount -f /Developer`

The original Pangu Developer folder will be restored, and you can reboot again!

***Original answer:***

<del>I've got the exact same problem. Don't really know what's causing this behavior. Maybe the fact that Pangu races iOS with an malformed DeveloperDiskImage.dmg?</del>

Yeah, it's because of Pangu. If you SSH into your 9.1 device, you'll see that there is a folder called Developer, with a file called neagent, which symlinks to /pguntether. I guess Pangu9 either still uses an exploit in neagent, or it's a leftover file from Pangu8. (Pangu8 used this trick to achieve a tethered jailbreak: https://cansecwest.com/slides/2015/CanSecWest2015_Final.pdf) Don't really know if I can delete it and then reboot, or if that would brick my device.

But I've found a way to still get the app on your device. Just go to Product > Archive, copy the .app from the contents, and sync it to your iPhone. Then just check the logs via the Devices window.

Comment: Could you clarify where to get ideviceimagemounter?  There is a user [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37123941/xcode-7-3-1-ios-9-1-jailbroken-please-check-your-setup-and-try-again-0xe) that is having trouble trying to use your solution.

Comment: Sure. Edited my answer and included a download link. Thanks for the heads up, hope that this works.

Comment: I have the same problem and started following your steps. When I execute the command, it says, no such directory found. Please help!!

Comment: Did you install Xcode? Xcode is needed for the Developer Images

Comment: Yes, I do have Xcode installed. It wasn't running at the time I went through your process. And what is Developer Images? So, here is the process that I did. I installed openSSH on my iPhone from cydia, since I didn't previously have it. I ran terminal on my mac. SSH into my iDevice, downloaded ideviceimagemounter(which is sitting in my downloads folder), and then executed `./ideviceimagemounter/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/9.1/DeveloperDiskImage.dmg` in terminal. After executing, it says no directory found

Comment: Ah I see, you're missing the space between ./ideviceimagemounter and /Applications/Xcode... Also the ideviceimagemounter command is meant to be executed on your OSX machine, not on the iDevice

Comment: Oh ok. When I ssh into iphone, its looking into iphone directory. Gotcha!! I don't understand step 4 and 5 then. I have the file saved in my downloads folder and when I'm in my downloads folder, how do I execute the command? I'm struggling a bit. Not much aware with this stuff. Sorry. I just executed the command in terminal, and I get same error; no such file or directory. `-bash: ./ideviceimagemounter: No such file or directory`

Comment: Are you sure the file is there? Check if the executable is in your Downloads directory, not in a subdirectory and then execute this command: ~/Downloads/ideviceimagemounter /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/9.1/DeveloperDiskImage.dmg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112590/discussion-between-sharukh-and-row-rocka).

Comment: This command gives me error Illegal instruction: 4.Could you please guide?

Comment: I accidentally deleted that neagent file from developer folder and rebooted but now my phone is not starting up.It stucked on boot logo.But I have backed up that file.What to do now.How can I put that file back?

Answer (score 0):

If your phone is jailbroken, just connect to your phone (by ssh, iFunBox, whatever), and clear all contents under directory `**/Developer/**'. Reconnect to Xcode and Xcode will regenerate the contents it needs. Then you'll be fine.

Comment: I deleted that and now my phone stuck on Apple logo.